# Overlapping Arrays in Julia - solutions with pointers?

Tags: pointers, julia

I have a large Float64 array `x` and often treat a slice of it as matrix before changing exactly that slice. Can I somehow refer to this slice as `y` which already has the correct shape. To

```
x=zeros(10000)
y=x[10:18]
reshape!(y,(3,3))
y=y+eye(3) # this doesn't change x
```

This does not work as `x[10:18]` creates a copy. I had a look at `pointer_to_array` but I couldn't work  it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following will do the job:

```
y = pointer_to_array( pointer( x, 10 ), (3,3) )   # make a slice starting from the 10th element
```

This can be tested, for example, as

```
x = zeros( 8 )
p = pointer_to_array( pointer( x, 3 ), (3,2) )
p[:,1] = 100.0
p[:,2] = 200.0
@show x    # => [ 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0, 200.0 ]
```

If the size of x is a multiple of the slice size, reshape() can also be used directly for modifying a slice. For example,

```
x = [ i for i=1:8 ]
s = reshape( x, (2,2,2) )
s[:,:,2] = 1000
@show x      # => [1,2,3,4,1000,1000,1000,1000]
```

Comment: @warsaga I have tried some more about this, and it seems that there is no bounds check for new array dimensions (i.e. "unsafe") https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/pointer.jl#L33  So please be careful when using this... I am wondering if other (safer) methods can be used for this (like subarray and arrayview)

Answer (score 3):

The usual tool of producing no-copy slices in julia is [SubArrays](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/devdocs/subarrays/):

```
x = zeros(10000)
y = sub(x, 10:18)
```

now changing `y` would change the corresponding elements of `x`.  (you can also use `slice`, which behaves differently with higher-dimensional arrays).

You can also use `y = sub(x, A)` where A is an array of indices. Unfortunately `reshape(y, 3, 3)` produces a copy  of the values by converting the SubArray to an Array (currently discussed in [Julia issue 9874](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/9874), so that may change in the future). Using `y = sub(x, A)` with `A` a matrix of indices of the right shape does not work.

Maybe for your particular application, it is sufficient to do

```
x = zeros(10000)
y = sub(x, 10:18)
y[:] += vec(eye(3))
```

which changes `x` as you wanted it, without producing a slice of different shape.

Comment: The last line (`y += vec(eye(3))`)  does *not* change `x`, since it is equivalent to `y = y + vec(eye(3))`, which assigns a *new* object to `y`.

Comment: You're right @DavidP.Sanders ; I meant to put `y[:]` on the lhs. Fixed.